# Javascript code to display music i'm listening to on phonegap app

Tags: javascript, phonegap

I'm actually working on a phonegap project and I'm stuck when it comes to create a  javascript code to show the music being played on the phone to my app, I want it to be just like on the Blackberry Messenger app music status. I don't want any music controller but just the title being displayed on my app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?
**PhoneGap Media Stream**
https://blog.phonegap.com/release-of-phonegap-media-stream-d53e5a5bfbf6